# Scaling button to maintain aspect on background-image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to scale my button's height appropriately so that the `background-image` properly fills out the entire image based on the new width of the button.

Here's the code I'm using which isn't working.

```
.auth-button {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-image: url(../img/auth/facebook-connect.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    padding: none;
    width: 90vw;
    height: calc(calc(161/953) * 90vw);
    max-width: 953px;
    max-height: 161px;
}
```

Please note that I'm using SCSS so there's actually not any nested calc()'s. In stead I have a variable set up `$authButtonAspect: calc(161/953)` and do `height: calc($authButtonAspect * 90vw)`

Ultimately, this should multiple the new width of the image (90% vertical width) by the aspect ratio and give a new height, but.. it doesn't.

161 is the height of the background image and 953 is the width of the background image.

**EDIT** Yes, I know I can do this in Javascript, looking for a CSS solution.

Answer (score 0):

The key point to remember when creating a responsive button with background image is that,

> the padding is always calculated based on the width.

Since height cannot be calculated in percentage, make the height of the button equals to `zero` and then control the button display height through either padding top or bottom.

When the parent element around the button resizes and there by increase the button width, results in the respective padding top calculation based on the current size of the element.

With above information, we can create a responsive button using css as shown below

```
a.img-btn
{
  background:url("../mybutton.jpg");
  width:50%;
  padding-top:50%; //Same width and padding will create a square
  height:0;
}
```

You can check more about [maintaining aspect ratio](http://davidsekar.com/css/maintain-aspect-ratio-of-a-responsive-element) over here

Check the sample CSS for a custom button for dimension that you've requested

```css
.btn{
background:transparent url("http://placehold.it/953x161") no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size:100% auto;
  width:75%;
  padding-top:13%;
  height:0;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
}

.btn span{display:none;}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn"><span>Test</span></a>
```

Comment: This does not work, and also seems like it would only work with a square. Background-image doesn't even show with height set to 0, as-well. I'm dealing with a 0.18~ aspect image. not 1:1.

Comment: That is a simple example, you can calculate the padding top %. I will update my answer in a minute